# I have high upload speeds but not able to video call properly

Tags: wireless-networking, upload, cisco-webex, google-meet

I have an internet connection that provides me with **wired** speeds of Download: 45 Mbps, Upload:60 Mbps.

But when I use a ADSL Wi-Fi Router, I get speed of Download: 20 Mbps, and Upload: 45 Mbps at the same location. Ping of 34 ms.

And yet I am not able to video call properly on Google Meet and Webex. My video is never visible to the person of the other side.
With zoom, I face this problems sometimes but most of the times my video is visible.

This has never been a problem with 3G and 4G internet connections that offer me an even lesser bandwidth and yet my video is always crystal clear to the person on the other side.

Comment: It's unlikely to be a simple speed issue, you can do video calls on 128kbps [badly, but you can] Ping 34 is slow, but it's not impossible. The actual bare minimum surprised me too - https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa1417/how-much-bandwidth-does-skype-need

Comment: Two points of failure that has nothing to do with speed and also would only impact other's view of you are: 1) the camera (and camera driver) functionality. What have you done to ensure that the camera is working; 2) are the experiences you describe all using the same device? Firewall rules can differ between devices and different software may be more successful at getting through a firewall "out of the box" without further configuration

Comment: @Yorik Hi. I have tried with different devices on the same network. The issue is the same(And I was wondering if it was because of the ISP or the wireless router). The camera works and video calling is nice when connected to mobile internet.

Comment: "_Download: 45 Mbps, Upload:60 Mbps_" seems very unlikely, particularly as you then mention ADSL. xDSL connections are typically asymmetric such that download is about 10x upload. In fact I've never encountered anywhere intentionally offering faster upload speeds than download. Are you sure these quoted speeds are correct?

Comment: I suggest contacting your ISP.

Comment: This could be bufferbloat, or at least you need to rule it out. When your home network is idle, run http://dslreports.com/speedtest to check your bufferbloat grade. If it's bad, use a site like https://www.stoplagging.com/ to learn about running SQM (Cake or FQ-CoDel) to fix bufferbloat.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is the issue relates to NAT (or carrier grade NAT). You can test the hypothesis by getting a VPN connection that offers a static IP.

VOIP connections can be tricky in a NAT environment as they try to negotiate a direct connection between the endpoints rather then run everything through the server.  NAT interferes with, and can break this negotiation.

If the problem goes away with your VPN, see if your ISP is doing carrier grade NAT. If it is, getting a connection without carrier grade nat could help.  Its also possible the issue is your router, or a combination if your isp and router.

(Its not really relevant  here but I think you have VDSL rather then ADSL - the idea - and often the  hardware - is the same but AFAIK ADSL cant reach the speeds you have)